# What is the password if we put blank in type password,retype password coln in the option of password change?

Tags: login, password

I have installed ubuntu 12.04,encrypting home folder.Later I wanted to remove password.Earlier I used windows OS.There was an option for without password in windows.
In ubuntu,while resetting password,I put nothing in the type password,retype password and I pressed enter key.After reboot ubuntu is asking password.I put my earlier password,without punnting any letter,just pressed enter and I tried all other options to login.But ubuntu says wrong password. What should I do to open my system?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solutions :

> If you have set password for root access then login as root and set
>   new password directly for your administrator login.... If you don't
>   set password for root just try it with blank.

OR

> If you boot from a LiveCD/USB and create a new user with a known
>   password you can copy the password hash from /etc/shadow in the live
>   filesystem to the shadow file in your usual file system on the disk,
>   then reboot and use the known password you copied across.

else follow this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860583.
Hope this will helps.